# String split fails due to unwanted delimiter

Tags: java, regex, split

This is the string I need to split for putting in map as key-val pair:

```
"jti":"4ef61081-e2e0-40e4-a9ad-8f2bf33f8923","exp":1525357546,"nbf":0,"iat":1525271146,"iss":"https://dev.open-sunbird.org/auth/realms/sunbird","aud":"admin-cli"
```

I tried with

`String[] parts = body.split(":|,");`

Problem with this approach is the ":" in https link. See the output as follows

```
--"jti"--"4ef61081-e2e0-40e4-a9ad-8f2bf33f8923"
--"exp"--1525357546
--"nbf"--0
--"iat"--1525271146
--"iss"--"https
--//dev.open-sunbird.org/auth/realms/sunbird"--"aud"
```

Any lead for the exact regex to solve the issue will be appreciated. (On top of my head is if we can do a check that every spitted word either starts and ends with " or doesn't start and end with ". But I feel that is a naive approach. even if we can do it.)

Comment: First split on comma, then find first colon and use substring

Comment: It's JSON, so use a JSON parser (example: https://github.com/google/gson)

Comment: See http://rextester.com/XJJT54366

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to get fancy with regex.  There are a couple options.

1. This is clearly claims / attributes on a JWT token.  Use a library to parse the JWT instead of parsing the string this way.
2. Just split first by commas, and then by the FIRST colon.  Should give you what you want without trying to respect the position of the quotes.
3. It's JSON, so use a JSON parser.